# Optimize multiple JOINs with large data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance, query-performance

I have 3 tables with this structure:

```
+-----------+   +-----------+   +-----------+
|   Files   |   | Programs  |   | Channels  |
|-----------|   |-----------|   |-----------|
|    ID     |   |    ID     |   |    ID     |
|   State   |   |   State   |   |   State   |
| ProgramID |   | ChannelID |   |    ...    |
|    ...    |   |    ...    |   |    ...    |
+-----------+   +-----------+   +-----------+
```

The tables `Files` and `Programs` has millions of records. When I run this query with one JOIN it's very fast (< 1 sec):

```sql
SELECT f.[ID] AS [ID], p.[Id] AS [ProgramID]
FROM dbo.[Files] f
INNER JOIN dbo.[Programs] p ON f.[ProgramID] = p.[ID] AND p.[State] = 1 
WHERE f.[State] = 1 
ORDER BY f.[ID] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

But if I add the second JOIN it will be very slow (about 12 sec):

```sql
SELECT f.[ID] AS [ID], p.[Id] AS [ProgramID]
FROM dbo.[Files] f
INNER JOIN dbo.[Programs] p ON f.[ProgramID] = p.[ID] AND p.[State] = 1 
INNER JOIN dbo.[Channels] c ON p.[ChannelID] = c.[ID] AND c.[State] = 1
WHERE f.[State] = 1 
ORDER BY f.[ID] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

I found out that it's because a very large data flowing from the first join, looking at the execution plan:

[image: execution plan]

Now, how can I increase the performance?

These are create table queries:

```sql
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Channels] ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Channels](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [State] [bigint] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [MyDatabase]
) ON [MyDatabase]

GO

CREATE INDEX IX_State ON [dbo].[Channels] ([State])
CREATE INDEX IX_TEST_Channels ON [dbo].[Channels] ([ID], [State])

GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Programs] ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Programs](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [State] [bigint] NULL,
    [ChannelID] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Programs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [MyDatabase]
) ON [MyDatabase] TEXTIMAGE_ON [MyDatabase]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Programs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Dbo.Programs_Dbo.Channels_ChannelID] FOREIGN KEY([ChannelID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Channels] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Programs] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Dbo.Programs_Dbo.Channels_ChannelID]
GO

CREATE INDEX IX_ChannelIDState ON [dbo].[Programs] ([ChannelID], [State])
CREATE INDEX IX_TEST_Programs ON [dbo].[Programs] ([ID], [State])

GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Files] ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [State] [bigint] NULL,
    [ProgramID] [bigint] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [MyDatabase]
) ON [MyDatabase] TEXTIMAGE_ON [MyDatabase]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Files]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Dbo.Files_Dbo.Programs_ProgramID] FOREIGN KEY([ProgramID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Programs] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Files] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Dbo.Files_Dbo.Programs_ProgramID]
GO

CREATE INDEX IX_ProgramIDState ON [dbo].[Files] ([ProgramID], [State])
CREATE INDEX IX_TEST_Files ON [dbo].[Files] ([ID], [State])

GO
```

Stats are up to date. I updated them again to be sure.

This is a shared database and I can't change the structure. The `State` column can have up to 10 possible values.